# Python format integer

Tags: python

I'm working with different BTC APIs and all of them provide BTC values in this format: 4140951 BTC which is obviously 0.04140951.

This code does the work but I don't think it's a good solution. Is there anything more simple that I can use?

```
   if len(amount) == 1:
        amount = "0.0000000" + str(amount)
        amount = float(amount)
    elif len(amount) == 2:
        amount = "0.000000" + str(amount)
        amount = float(amount)
    elif len(amount) == 3:
        amount = "0.00000" + str(amount)
        amount = float(amount)
    elif len(amount) == 4:
        amount = "0.0000" + str(amount)
        amount = float(amount)
    elif len(amount) == 5:
        amount = "0.000" + str(amount)
        amount = float(amount)
    elif len(amount) == 6:
        amount = "0.00" + str(amount)
        amount = float(amount)
    elif len(amount) == 7:
        amount = "0.0" + str(amount)
        amount = float(amount)
    elif len(amount) == 8:
        amount = "0." + str(amount)
        amount = float(amount)
```

Comment: What is the type of amount? It looks like it is a string because you are testing `len(amount)`, but then again, in that case you would not do `str(amount)`, would you?

Answer (score 1):

I believe you are receiving the value expressed in [Satoshi](https://en.bitcoin.it/wiki/Satoshi_(unit)). To convert to Bitcoin, just divide by 100,000,000:

```
>>> 4140951 / 100000000
0.04140951
```

Comment: Yes, and if correct replaceable with scientific notation: `1e8`

Comment: @AntonvBR Note, however, that `100000000` is not exactly the same as `1e8` - former is an integer and latter a floating point number.

Comment: Since original code is testing `len(amount)`, then amount is probably a string and needs to be converted to int before the division.

Answer (score 0):

Divideret by 100000000? Would That not work